# C# IOS Set event handler to table rows

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm using a UITableViewController.

Instead of displaying an alert view I want to be redirected to another page after i touch a particular row in a table.

I have this code but it doesn't work

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
    tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // normal iOS behaviour is to remove the blue highlight

    //call the next screen
    if(this.accountRegistration== null) {
        this.accountRegistration = new AccountRegistration();
    } 

    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(this.accountRegistration,    true); 

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Do you get an error message?

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint near the `show`?

Comment: I got this error message: object reference not set to an instance of an object in this part of code  this.NavigationController.PushViewController(this.accountRegistration,    true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works well

[Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow window;
        UINavigationController rootNavigationController;

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        this.window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds); 
        //---- instantiate a new navigation controller 
        this.rootNavigationController = new UINavigationController(); 
        this.rootNavigationController.PushViewController(new MyUITableViewController(), false);

        //---- set the root view controller on the window. the nav 
        // controller will handle the rest
        this.window.RootViewController = this.rootNavigationController;
        this.window.MakeKeyAndVisible (); 
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm changing my answer because I didn't realize you were using a UITableViewController.

In your AppDelegate.cs file you need to set the rootNavigationController to a new UINavigationController:

```
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow window;
        UINavigationController rootNavigationController;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            this.window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds); 
            //---- instantiate a new navigation controller 
            this.rootNavigationController = new UINavigationController(); 
            this.rootNavigationController.PushViewController(new MyUITableViewController(), false);

            //---- set the root view controller on the window. the nav 
            // controller will handle the rest
            this.window.RootViewController = this.rootNavigationController;
            this.window.MakeKeyAndVisible (); 
            return true;
        }

        ....
```

From that point on, your UITableViewController should always have a reference to this.NavigationController.

Comment: I got this error message: object reference not set to an instance of an object in this part of code  this.NavigationController.PushViewController(this.accountRegistration,    true);

Comment: I didn't realized you were using a UITableViewController. I have edited my answer to better reflect this.